# Multiple formula In One Cell

Tags: excel

Trying to do a work rotation timesheet.

I have `=(j11-10)×24 =(j13-j12)×24` one formula per cell

How would i put multiples of the above all into one cell?

Thanks

Comment: Please add details as what you are expecting as a result.  Do you want to see the answer to each of the individual formulas in the same cell, using a separator?

Answer (score 2):

String the two results together.

```
=(j11-10)×24 & " " & (j13-j12)×24
```

Change the space to a hyphen, comma or whatever you want as a list separator.

Comment: Thanks thats great.how would i be able to add them together instead of a list seperator... so =(j11-j10)×24 + the next etc

Comment: I'm unclear on what you are trying to do but I think you might have used `10` in your original formula when you meant `J10`. Please clarify your intention by editing your question above and offering any corrections as well as hte results you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sum formula and have all your formulas separated by commas to add each equation:

```
=Sum((J11-J10)*24, (J13-J12)*24, nextformula, nextformula, etc.)
```